# Magento 2 , query insert/update statments not binding with '?' variables

Tags: php, magento, single-sign-on

application works fine binding when used locally however via sso the binding seems to fail

- ie update

  UPDATE `users` SET `login_date` = NOW(), `logins` = ? WHERE (id = 1)
- the update statement updates the record as I can see a change date on it however values are not bound.